# migrating from 1.5 to joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, migrate

Im having huge problems with migrating from 1.5 to 2.5 I bought SPUpgrade but still have no real luck. Not sure what Im doing wrong..

Is there a fail proof way to mirgrate old 1.5 joomla websites into 2.5?

Thanks

Comment: What problem you are facing? Have you tried with JUpgrade. I have used Jupgrade to migrate 2-3 joomla 1.5 sites to 2.5. It works like a charm.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information e.g. what went wrong, what extensions you have and so on. Updating core only with with spupgrade or jupgrade works fine.

Comment: thanks for the help. I did use JUpgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it with this already?http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5

Take your time, this is not an easy task, set up a testing environment, do backups, check requirements and all the stuff we all hate to do :-)

Good Luck.